# How can I check if user enter correct username password and database name?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, oracle11g

I have below form and I like to give user alert if any of the below entry is not correct. Where can add my exception below code?

[image]

***MYcode:***

```
 public static void GetTables(Members src)
    {

        OracleConnection conn1 = MyConnectionClass.GetConnection(src.DB, src.ID, src.Password);

        conn1.Open();
        using (OracleCommand command= new OracleCommand("SELECT * FORM DBA_USERS WHERE USER NAME=" + src.ID + " and PASSWORD=" + src.Password + "", conn1))
        {
            using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                int count = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) is going to wreak havok on your application.  Consider using parameterized queries to defend against such users.

Comment: I certainly hope that `src.Password` contains the hashed password, not the password in plain text.

Comment: Well what keeps you from achieving your goal?

Comment: @TimS. That is whats troubling you in this code? really?

Comment: @Omribitan no, the SQL injection is the main thing, but Servy already covered that, so I figured I'd point out the syntax error. =)

Comment: I want to show user messageBox.Show("//enter alert here");

Comment: there is sql injection here because I hased my password and other information

Comment: @user2760129 Please be more specific on what your problem is? if you what to show a message box with an alert, what is keeping you from doing that?

Comment: You not supposed to tell user "your password is wrong." You must say "your login is wrong"

Comment: To check database name you just connect to it and if connection is open, you are good. Then you start testing user info.

Comment: If you get a connection the ID and Password are correct if you do not get a connect they are not. So you will get a error throw and the user will know.

Comment: I think I'm actually in shock; if someone wants to connect to the database let them try. If they fail then catch the error and deal with it. Don't try to re-implement Oracle's security. Your version is going to be nowhere near as good (and you've just granted everyone access to your user lists and hashed passwords that might be vulnerable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just looked at the code again and this is total disaster.
So you are telling me that connection that established by application has access to DBA_Users table? This is a red flag of great size.

You should:

- create a schema which will be your application schema
- use pwd and username for that schema in connection string, have it encrypted, unreachable by user
- within your application have table that called not just "users" but something like "users1f0tm34m".
- use that table to verify your application incoming user.

Basically, you will establish connection using your applications encrypted conn string. This is where you check if the connection is right. The second check will be against your table if the user credentials are right.

Now, you need to stop argument about this:

```
"SELECT * FROM DBA_USERS WHERE USERNAME=" + src.ID + " and PASSWORD=" + src.Password + ""
```

Besides SQL injection there is optimization. This code above will cause oracle optimizer create a plan for the query every time next user logs on. To avoid this you need to use bind variables via parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_USERS WHERE USERNAME=:uname and PASSWORD=:pwd
```

This is Oracle recommended way and what you did is dynamic SQL which is Oracle non-recommended.

If your company ever has an audit, you're cooked.